# Unskilled work requiring skilled people

Tags: job-search, career-switch, skills

Let's say someone has knowledge (and diplomas) in academic disciplines (philosophy, fundamental mathematics, fundamental computer science or anything that may not be directly useful outside a research office...) and that he wants to leave academics, office jobs or computer jobs.

He wants to leave those work fields to find jobs somehow more related to nature (seas, forests, mountains, outdoor experiences...) and people. But he has no skills related to such jobs (manual skills, mountain knowledge, sea experience...) and he would like to find something that will not virtually wipe out his many years of training.

Thus, the question: what kind of (technically) unskilled such jobs (or occupations) may require soft-skills thats derives from such academic training (and obviously, possibly other soft-skill like social-based soft-skills or athletic abilities) ?

*Note:* I wrote "occupation" to convey the idea that it may be something that one does for maybe a few years as much as a life-long job.

Answer (score 9):

Many outdoors jobs require little to no skill apart from being healthy and willing to work.

You'd be surprised how many well educated and certified people are hiding away in the back of beyond doing them.

Forestry work springs to mind, planting, spraying, not so much logging unless you know how to use tools. Plenty of forestry jobs in my foreman days I'd give a new hire 5 minutes training and they're good to go.

> What are your skills good for?

Apart from social ones, they're good for discussion, a bit of teaching perhaps, a different perspective to see things from. Not a lot else in an unskilled position. However, what you do come from academia with that is very useful is regardless of what you studied, you learnt HOW to study something and how to focus and understand issues. Thinking things through is a valuable asset in any job.

> will not virtually wipe out his many years of training.

You don't lose knowledge just because you change lifestyle, you can carry on your interests in an amateur fashion or just retain what you have. In fact in some fields you may get new insights.

I've NEVER had a job in the field I studied at Uni as an adult, yet I kept interest through several career and country changes and my amateur publications have earned me a fair bit of money, notoriety, and gotten me an audience with a King.